# Ceiling fan switch tripping breaker

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan previously operated with a wall switch which controlled the light, and a pull chain which controlled the fan speed independent of the switch. After disconnecting and reconnecting due to loose bracket screws, the light now operates by pull chain only (similar to the fan speed). Oddly, if the wall switch is turned on, the fan hums for a second before the breaker trips.

Wires from the ceiling are white, black, and brown/bare (assume this to be the ground). The fan wires are blue, white, black, and green. I've connected green to green, white to white, and blue & black to black.

What am I missing? Should the light (blue wire) also be connected to the white ceiling wire? Or is there something else I should troubleshoot?

Thank you in advance.[image]!

Comment: Can you spin the fan freely when the fan is switched off?  Also, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: How was it wired previously? Or did the wiring not change?

Comment: How is the switch wired?

Comment: If the wiring did not change (it sounds correct). The fan may be bound up as  ThreePhaseEel is suggesting. Make sure it turns freely when off. +

Comment: The fan works just fine without the use of the wall switch - pull chain changes the speed. I assume it's not connected the same way as it was before, but the wiring of the switch or the ceiling did not change. I'll try to post a picture of the "before" connection.

Comment: In the photo, the black goes to black (up in the ceiling), white goes to white (though there is a lot of blk electrical tape on it), and it appears the blue goes to the brown wire on the left. These are the only 3 from the ceiling, So I guess my question is where should the green ground from the fan be connected? I've read a couple other forums about a "high" hot and "low" hot but not sure if that's what's going on here. I'll look at the switch in the wall which hopefully also has the brown wire so I'll know the light should connect to the switch rather than the hot black.

Comment: Is this a standard breaker that's tripping, or a GFCI or an AFCI?